# WifiP2PManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION is broadcasting instead of WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION when connected to a peer

Tags: android, kotlin, wifimanager, wifip2p

I am trying to connect two devices using WifiP2Pmanager in android.
Able to list the peers and connect the selected device.

Below given code snippet executes when a peer is selected to connect

```
val device = deviceArray[position]
        val config = WifiP2pConfig()
        config.deviceAddress = device.deviceAddress
        config.wps.setup = WpsInfo.PBC

        channel?.also { channel ->
            manager?.connect(channel, config, object : WifiP2pManager.ActionListener {
            override fun onSuccess() {
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Connected to " + device.deviceName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }

            override fun onFailure(reason: Int) {
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Not Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }

       )}
```

But after the peer connection, the intent broadcasting is WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION instead of WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION. Trying on the device with android version 7.
I followed all the steps and code as explained in android [WifiDirect](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p#kotlin) .

This is my onReceive code part in BroadcastReceiver implementation.

```
override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
    val action: String? = intent.action
    when (action) {
        WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION -> {
            // Check to see if Wi-Fi is enabled and notify appropriate activity
            val state = intent.getIntExtra(WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_WIFI_STATE, -1)

            if (state == WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_ENABLED) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Wifi is ON", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Wifi is OFF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
        WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION -> {
            // Call WifiP2pManager.requestPeers() to get a list of current peers
            if (manager != null) {
                manager.requestPeers(channel, activity.peerListListener);
            }
        }
        WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION -> {
            // Respond to new connection or disconnections
            if (manager == null) {
                return
            }

            if (isNetworkAvailable(context)) {
                activity.connectionStatus.setText("Device Connected")
                manager.requestConnectionInfo(channel, activity.connectionInfoListener)

            } else {
                activity.connectionStatus.setText("Device Disconnected")
            }
        }
        WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION -> {
            // Respond to this device's wifi state changing
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated..